# Front derailleur will not sit properly on large cog without chain rub

Tags: bottom-bracket, adjustment, derailleur-front, barrel-adjuster

I bought a Vilano Commuter bike ( 3x7 speed ) a while back and recently upgraded the front derailleur, crankset, brifters, pedals and rear derailleur to tourney A070 components. However, I can't seem to get the front derailleur to sit on the large cog with no chain rub when the rear derailleur is on the smallest cog.

The cable is as taught as it could possibly get and the inline barrel adjuster is also on it's most tense setting. I'm at a loss trying to determine why the FD won't make it passed the largest cog, the FD H limit is as loose as possible and the L limit is sitting as close to the small cog without chain rub ( ~1mm ) when on the largest rear cog.. am I missing something here? Do I have BB that is too elongated?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be the wrong bb spindle length perhaps. what does the chainline measure as?

Answer (score 1):

You say you replaced the the derailleurs, crankset, brifters and pedals, but not the bottom bracket.

My initial thought is that your crank is too far outboard because it requires a shorter bottom bracket axle than your previous crank.

The location of the square taper hole relative to the rings is different for different cranks, so different axle lengths are required to get the correct chain line (distance middle ring from center plane if the frame).

In your first picture the distance between the cranks and bracket shell does appear to be quite large.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. Although, what's throwing me off is that I wasn't really able to make clearance passed the third and largest cog with the previous components either.

Comment: It's a square tapered BB and the previous components was this sunrace FD and this no name brand crank with a sunrace freewheel.

Comment: There’s a fairly easy check you can do, measure center of seat tube to middle ring, it should be about 47.5mm for an MTB triple (see [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/chainline.html#standards) ) this would also apply to a commuter with Tourney components.